# the phrase "from now on" to be used in similar phrases

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

All of us know that "from now on" means starting from now, for example:

From now on, all of us have to turn our mobiles off.

But is this term assignable to such phrase?

From lesson three on...
(I mean starting from the lesson three...)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use constructions like "*From lesson three on*. Depending on where you're from, it may or may not be more idiomatic to phrase it "*From lesson three **onwards***".

Comment: Assume you are a teacher and are discussing the following course which is about four month. You say, from lesson three on, we will have video conferences...

Comment: Like I said, it's perfectly fine to use "From lesson three on, ..." and another option is "From less three onwards, ...".

Answer (score -1):

"From now on" means "from this moment". More spesifically, it means strating from this moment or strating now. And it automatically implies that it will be that way into the future and not just happen in one little moment and stop and never reoccur.

Comment: This does not answer the question posed.

Answer (score -2):

"From now on" doesn't mean "starting from now." (You would just say, "Turn your phones off, now") It's more accurately used as "In the (near or distant) future, when one finds oneself in the same (or similar) situation."

Comment: I disagree. Can you provide some evidence of this claim?

Comment: It just seems like "from now on" would be used after something unfortunate had occurred - to insure an alternate outcome. "From now on, we won't try to hard-boil eggs in the microwave." It has kind of a reset/do-over connotation to it.

Comment: It can be used in that context, of course. In that context it **still** means starting now and continuing through the future. It does not mean that it might start to be true only at some time "*in the (near or distant) future*".  It starts **now**, just as it says. Unless you can show some evidence of that other meaning.

Answer (score -2):

"From now on" means forever, or at least for the foreseeable future. "I'm going to keep my front door locked at night from now on." You wouldn't keep your mobile phones turned off forever! I would expect you to say "Let's turn off our mobiles now" (just for the duration of our meeting, etc), or "From now on, let's turn off our mobiles during meetings."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about applying the concept to different starting points in the future.